# How to get a image to appear in a toplevel widget in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

The problem with this code is that , i  know the actual .png file isnt corrupted , I've tested it multiple times in other projects , im not sure why my `photo1`
image isnt appearing inside of my `Toplevel` window. Any Reason why this is occuring in my toplevel widget and how to fix it?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
#placing of the window
w = 600
h = 250
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))
#Window title 
root.title(string=  "Longwood Panther Math Game Main Menu")
#The window configuration 
root.resizable(width = False , height = False)
#level variable 








def language_Arts(a):
  root.withdraw()
  language_window = Toplevel()
  language_window.iconbitmap('panther.ico')
  #title
  language_window.title(string = 'Language Arts Main Menu')
  #placing of the window
  w = 500
  h = 250
  ws = language_window.winfo_screenwidth()
  hs = language_window.winfo_screenheight()
  x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
  y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
  language_window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))
  #Greetings
  Greetings =Message(language_window , text = 'Welcome to The Language Arts Section, this is Where you Can Brush up on Your Grammar , and improve gramatical errors. With Multiple levels based on your skill level(grade classification)'  , font= 'times 10 bold')
  Greetings.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we') 
  #elementary
  elementary = ttk.Button(language_window , text = 'Elementary')
  elementary.grid(row  = 2 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
  #middle school button
  middleschool = ttk.Button(language_window ,text = 'Middle School')
  middleschool.grid(row = 2 , column  = 2 , sticky = 'we')
  #highschool button
  highschool = ttk.Button(language_window , text = 'High School')
  highschool.grid(row = 2 , column = 3, sticky = 'we')
  # photos
  photo1 = PhotoImage(file = 'grammar-cartoon.png')
  photo2 = PhotoImage(file ='Matt1-240x3005.png')
  #image labels
  image1 = Label(language_window , image = photo1)
  image1.grid(row = 3 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')



LA_Button = ttk.Button(root , text= 'Language Arts')
LA_Button.grid(row = 4 , column = 4, sticky = 'we')
LA_Button.bind('<Button-1>' , language_Arts)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need a _global_ reference to images or they get garbage collected, as in removed from memory. Learn more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function). `photo1` is a _local_ variable, as in it is only available while under `language_Arts`. You can easily avoid this renaming it to `image1.photo1`.

Comment: See [this](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) for more info.

Comment: Make sure you first assign `image1` as a label as in `image1 = Label(...)`, _then_ assign `image1.photo1 = PhotoImage...` and then configure image for the label like `image1['image'] = image1.photo1`.

Comment: @Nae so to get a clear understanding of what you are trying to say , without going to much of research , we have to reference the image/photo of our label a second time?so it doenst get garbage collected by python?

Comment: Not your label, but your image that is currently held by `photo1` variable. And not twice, but rather only once but as a _global_ variable. I'm not saying you shouldn't research. I'm just saying that I _could_ make the image appear on my end using what I've commented and posts that I've linked with the code you've provided.